# Understanding Screw Axes in Crystallographic Space Groups

Tags: group-theory, euclidean-geometry, discrete-geometry, crystallography

I'm having trouble understanding how a 'screw axis' actually acts as on $\mathbb{E}^3$ as an element of a space group. Everything I talk about here will be in 3 dimensions. [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/crystallographic+group) defines a space (or crystallographic) group as a subgroup $G$ of the Euclidean group $\mathrm{E}(3)$ for which there exists a lattice $L$ in $\mathbb{E}^3$ such that $G\subseteq\mathrm{Aut}(L)$ and such that $G$ contains all translations by elements of $L$.

Let's consider a very simple example of a space group which contains a screw axis—$P222_1$ (note that I am using [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_space_groups#List_of_Orthorhombic) as my source for lists of space groups). If I understand Hermann–Mauguin notation correctly (which I probably don't), we choose 3 positive numbers $a,b$ and $c$, and then the group $P222_1$ with respect to this basis is generated by: all translations by elements of the lattice $L=\mathbb{Z}\langle (a,0,0),(0,b,0),(0,0,c) \rangle$; rotation by $\pi$ about the $x$-axis; rotation by $\pi$ about the $y$-axis; and the combination of rotation by $\pi$ about the $z$-axis and translation by $(0,0,c/2)$.

Now, *if this is correct,* then it is quite clear to me that the orbit of the origin under $P222_1$ is not $L$, but the lattice $L'=\mathbb{Z}\langle (a,0,0),(0,b,0),(0,0,c/2) \rangle$; and $P222_1$ contains all translations by elements of this lattice and preserves this lattice. Thus it is exactly the same as the group $P222$ with respect to the basis $a,b$ and $c/2$, requiring no screw axes to generate it. So $P222_1$ is a completely redundant symbol.

What have I done wrong here? It's driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1):

Hermann–Mauguin notation is sneaky. It tells you the *nature* of a crystal's symmetry when viewed along certain axes, but not the precise *realisations* of those symmetries. It does not tell you the positions of rotation and screw axes in the unit cell, for example.

In your case, the symbols $\mathrm P222_1$ do not tell you that the "rotation by $\pi$ about the $x$-axis" should instead be a rotation by $\pi$ **about the line $\left(0,0,\frac14\right)+(1,0,0)\lambda$** (which is parallel to the $x$-axis).

With this replacement, the generating set you have described is $\{(x,-y,-z+c/2),(-x,y,-z),(-x,-y,z+c/2)\}$ and correctly describes $\mathrm P222_1$. But now note that the first generator is the composition of the other two modulo the lattice translations. Hence a minimal generating set for $\mathrm P222_1$ is $\{(-x,y,-z),(-x,-y,z+c/2)\}$, showing that there are $4$ fundamental domains in its unit cell.